# Merge/rebase branches across repos

Tags: git, github

I have a local repo which i was using to commit. Let's call this `A` with branch named `implementation`

I also have a github repo which was used for production deployment. Let's call this `B`. `A` is sub repo of `B` which also has the branch `implementation` (`A` is in the `web` folder). It was copied before I made changes. Let's call it `C`

Now i was committing all my changes to `A` in `implementation` branch. I want to merge into `C`'s `implementation` branch.

Comment: Don't know how to face this problem. But I don't understand why at some point you created two different repos, instead of a `master` and a `develop` branch, as recommended by the [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: In C's repository you could fetch `implementation` from `A`(the local `A` or the github `A`) and then merge it. `git fetch <path_to_local_A/url_to_github_A> implementation && git merge FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: @EuGENE true. Didn't think too much as this is a personal project :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add your github repo as a remote of your local repository:

```
git remote add <name_for_remote> <github_repo_url>
```

where `<name_for_remote>` is an arbitrary name for your remote github repository and `<github_repo_url>` is its' adress.

You also have to `fetch` once to know what's going on upstream:

```
git fetch <name_for_remote>
```

Then, you can set the upstream for your local `implementation` branch:

```
git branch -u <name_for_remote>/implementation
```

Your local `implementation` should be your current checked out branch.

If you `git push` now, the changes from your local `implementation` branch will  be pushed to the github `implementation` branch. This will, however, only work without conflicts if the remote branch was not changed since you copied your local repo. You would have to `pull`, `rebase` or force push in this case, depending on which changes you want to keep.

---

Your workflow here looks strange, however. Did you really copy the repository? Why not just clone it, to have your github repo set as the default remote `origin`? Also, by "sub repo" you mean a copy, as in `cp`? Also, what does repository `B` have to do with any of this? You may have to elaborate on which repo was copied/cloned from which to allow a proper answer to your question.

Comment: note that A is subrepo of B. How do I set an upstream to folder in B?

Comment: i did a fetch, then pull and pushed my latest changes :) works fine

Comment: To answer your questions. A is the frontend code and B is the backend code. To make the build easier I have copied B into A/web/ folder.